# Notification Music on buntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have an Ubuntu phone, which i set some mp3 files as ringtones for calls and messages. The ringtne that is set for the messages plays the whole way through even though you have read the message, while the call ringtone stops as soon as you answer it. Have also tried using .ogg files but that didnt help. 
Is there a fix or will i be best to report as a bug.

Comment: I think this is expected behaviour. You should use a short sound for a message rather than a whole song.